# Aggregate SUM with Doctrine2 and QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sum, query-builder, symfony-2.2

in my repository class I have this, but the query is not working.

```
 public function getResultsByName($page, $resultsCount, array $request_arr){     
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('xx'); 
 $qb->addSelect('SUM(xx.quantity) as total')
    ->leftJoin('xx.reception', 'x')
    ->addSelect('x')
    ->leftJoin('x.purchase', 'p')
    ->addSelect('p')
    ->leftJoin('p.provider', 'pr')
    ->addSelect('pr')
    ->where('pr.id = :company_id')
    ->setParameter('company_id', $request_arr['company_id']);

 $query = $qb->getQuery(); 

 return parent::getPaginator($query, $page, $resultsCount); }
```

The error is appearing in my twig template this is the important chunk of it

```
    {% for result in results %}
<tr>
    <td>{{result.reception.id}}</td>
    <td>{{result.reception.date|date('d-m-Y')}}</td>
    <td>{{result.reception.purchase.id}}</td>
    <td>{{result.reception.purchase.provider.name|upper}} [{{result.reception.purchase.provider.id}}]</td>
    <td>{{result.purchaseProduct.name |upper}} [{{result.purchaseProduct.productCode |upper}}]</td>
    <td>{{result.purchasePrice}}</td>
    <td>{{result.quantity}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{result.quantityStock}}</td>
</tr>   
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? What exactly error do you have?

Comment: The error is appearing in TWIG template, this is the eror:Item &quot;sale&quot; for &quot;Array&quot; does not exist in &quot;AgroMyEntityManagerBundle:MyEntityManager:Sale/SaleProductSaleList.html.twig&quot; at line 14, look abov I added my template code

Comment: It's not because of sum. You're trying to access the `result.sale` property that doesn't exist.

Comment: No sorry, well my current error is this: Item &quot;reception&quot; for &quot;Array&quot; does not exist in &quot;AgroMyEntityManagerBundle:MyEntityManager:Purchase/PurchaseProductReceptionList.html.twig&quot; at line 15 (500 Internal Server)

Comment: I have updated template code, but all work perfectly once I remove this line addSelect('SUM(xx.quantity) as total')

Answer (score 3):

as you have two selects on your query, your result object is an array of this kind:

```
array(
    'total' => $total,
    'xx' => array(
        'reception' => $reception,
        'quantityStock' => $quantityStock,
        [...]
    ) 
);
```

To access your properties in twig, you have to access it like that:

```
{{result.xx.reception}}
{{result.total}}
```

Comment: even adding xx in my loop like this {% for result in results %} {{result.xx.quantity}} ... {% endfor %} doesn't work. I'm getting just the same error.

Comment: I've edited my answer, the "quantity" is aliased as "total" in your SUM, other properties as "reception" must be available from {{result.xx.reception}}

Comment: Unfortunately neither quantity or the others properties(reception) are accessed, it might be something else wrong.